# install c libraries in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, include, cs50

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW7iC.jpg)

I do this after the teacher but there is a problem.

```
cc     calculator.c   -o calculator
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc calculator.c -o calculator, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [<builtin>: calculator] Error 2
```

Comment: The course you're watching doesn't cover the parts of installing a C compiler, which is needed (Visual Studio Code does not include a C compiler)- and that particular piece of code seems to also require a somewhat specific environment (as indicated by the cs50.h header file used) that students at harward perhaps gets as part of enrolling in that class.